# Angular12 Upgarde: Warning: 1 rules skipped due to selector errors: .k-input-label:dir(rtl) -> unmatched pseudo-class :dir

Tags: angular-cli, angular12

I have upgraded my application to Angular 12.But getting a below warning while running ng serve
Warning: 1 rules skipped due to selector errors:
.k-input-label:dir(rtl) -> unmatched pseudo-class :dir)

Whereas no .k-input-label:dir(rtl) is being used in the application. My application is not loading in the browser due to the following error. It would be great if someone can help me to resolve this warning.
Thanks in advance.